# Help with JSP/Servlets...?

Tags: jsp, servlets, mapping

I am tying to design a simple login. I have a DB running on MySQL.... I created a Login page which has a form.

```
<form action="login" name="login" method="post">
                <div id="contents" >
                   <table  width="400" border="0">
                       <tr>
                            <td height="44" width="100" style="color: white;">User Name: 
                            </td>
                           <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text" />


                          </td>
                       </tr>
                      <tr>
                              <td height="44" style="color: white;">Password: 
                                 </td>
                             <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
                             </td>
                       </tr>

                        <tr>
                           <td height="60">&nbsp;
                             </td>
                           <td><input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return validate()"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                     </table>

                  </div>


           </form>
```

Also have a Login.java file.... in the package called functions.... Now i'm trying to do the servlet mapping but i'm not sure wad i'm doing wrong cause i keep getting

> HTTP Status 404 - /Wifi/login
>   type Status report
>
> message /Wifi/login
>
> description The requested resource (/Wifi/login) is not available.

This is what i have in the web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>logicalName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>functions.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logicalName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Would really appreciate the help cause i'm lost....!!!

I had my web.xml in the wrong place but now that i put it inside web-inf...

i start getting this error

> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
> ```
>
> functions.Login
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: functions.Login
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

But my Login.Java class exists....!!!

Comment: Read the server logs. The servlet has likely failed to initialize. The log should contain an exception which in turn should contain the answer to the problem.

Comment: Thanks... but where can i find the logs ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, I think.  It seem to me that the only problem is the `action` attribute on your form.  Does it work any better if you do:

```
<form action="/login" name="login" method="post">
```

Comment: Hm, so then something else is not working.  Do you see any stack-traces in your server log?

Comment: I see.  Have you inspected the .war file generated by your build (you can inspect it using any zip program like WinZip or WinRAR)?  If you've done everything correctly you should have `Login.class` file under `<war>/WEB-INF/classes/functions`.  If it is not there then your webapp is not being packaged correctly.

Comment: i dont think thats getting generated

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: functions.Login

The file `/WEB-INF/classes/functions/Login.class` is missing.

Compile the `functions/Login.java` using `javac` with the `Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar` in the classpath and then put the generated`functions/Login.class` file there in the `/WEB-INF/classes`.

> *But my Login.Java class exists*

That's not a class file. That's a Java source file. The class file has the `.class` extension and is to be generated by `javac` based on the `.java` file.